# SQL query improvement - MSAccess 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a need to Select all records based on the following SQL:

```
Select ID, ID2 From Table1 Where ID2 NOT IN (Select ID2 From Table2 Where ID3 IN (151,157))
```

There are 171k records in Table1 and 70k records in Table2 where 'ID3 IN (151,157)'.

Unfortunately, that query takes forever; in fact, I have never seen it complete on a system with 32GB memory and quad I7 processors. I give up and cancel after 30 minutes.

I figure there is an SQL guru or two here that can tell me how to improve this query and get it to complete in under a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try joining the subquery:

```
Select ID, ID2
From Table1
LEFT JOIN 
(Select ID2
 From Table2
 Where ID3 IN (151,157))
WHERE ID2 IS NULL
```

If that doesn't work, I would consider creating the subquery as temp table and referencing that.

Comment: The syntax of your query above produces an error in MSAccess 2007.
But, your idea of creating a temp table with the subquery and then running the join on that as per above works very well, and in under 5 seconds for both creating the temp table and the join query!!! Thanks!